# React memo: compare children coming prevProps and nextProps

Tags: reactjs

Is there any way that I can deep compare the children coming from prevProps and nextProps while using `React.memo`?

```
const ContentWrapper = React.memo(({children}) => {
    return children
}, function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
    if (prevProps.children === nextProps.children) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second argument to do the deep compare yourself:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

To compare those objects (since react nodes are internally just objects), you can use lodash isEqual function or write it yourself like this:

```
var deepEqual = function (x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return true;
  }
  else if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;

    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {  
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  else 
    return false;
}
```

Or you could stringify both prop objects and compare those strings, but that would be would be quite slow.

Comment: That's what he's doing - I think his question is about how to deep compare React nodes.

Comment: @Domino987 Thanks. Check it out I found something eligible for this requirement

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-fast-compare